# Yaru/Communitheme 18.04

Tags: 18.04

How can I set *Communitheme* as the default theme for all users in 18.04. Even for when I create a new user?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out. I had to rename ubuntu.desktop in /usr/share/xsessions

```
sudo mv /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop-backup
```